# how to setup test suite in ruby?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

i am writing few ruby scripts and i wanted to write Unit tests and integration tests for it.

i learnt that test/unit module is present in ruby.

in my scripts, i wrote ruby classes A and B which extends the common helper class Common

in both the class, i am trying to setup S3 connections.

i wrote A_test, B_test test cases.

when i run them individually, they work.

when i put together, they are not working. some of the variable in the initialize are getting set only for the class / tests which runs first.

if A_test is running first, then it works.
B_test doesnt work.

any reason?

Comment: You need to supply examples of the tests.

Answer (score 0):

I can not answer your question well without some code samples, but consider the possibility that it's the code being tested that's the problem, not the tests.